# Is the norm of invertible linear transformation finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In finite dimension linear space, due to singular value it is right.

But is it right in infinite dimension linear space?

Is the norm needs to be complete to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need not to be true. Take any normed $X$ space with norm $||\cdot ||$ and take a Hamel basis $B=\{e_t:t\in T\}$ such that $||e_t||= 1 $ for all $t\in T.$ Take a subset $B_1=\{e_{t_n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and define an operator $A:X\to X$ by $Ae_{t_n} =ne_{t_n}$ for $t_n \in B_1$ and $Ae_t =e_t $ for $t\in B\setminus B_1 .$
Clearly, $A$ is invertible operator but $$||A||=\sup_{||x||=1} ||Ax||\geq ||Ae_{t_n} ||\geq n $$ for all $n.$